Обращение к объекту класса из класса в другом файле
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки btn1 
окно toplevel закрывается и при этом мне нужно чтобы title_info изменил текст на var из класса Top(), который в другом файле?
main.py:
import customtkinter
import test2 as t2


class Frame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.put_widget()

    def action_btn_signin(self):
# +++
        # main.title_info.configure(text="Open Toplevel")             # +++
        t2.Top()

    def put_widget(self):
        self.btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="open toplevel", command=self.action_btn_signin)
        self.btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")


class Main(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.put_widget()

    def put_widget(self):
        self.title_info = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Docs")
        self.title_info.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.info_frame = Frame(self)
        self.info_frame.configure(corner_radius=14)
        self.info_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(20, 5), pady=(20, 5))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()

Когда все классы в одном файле, то все работает, но стоит резнести по фалам то выдает ошибку, что "у класса такого атрибута нет"
test2.py
import customtkinter
import test

class Top(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.put_widget()
        self.var = "main_window"

    def pass_to_main(self): 
        # Main.Main.title_info.configure(text=self.var)
# !!! +++
        test.title_info.configure(text=self.var) # title_info изменил текст на var
        self.destroy()                           # +++ окно toplevel закрывается
        
    def put_widget(self):
        self.btn1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, width=200, text="push", corner_radius=24, font=("Arial", 18), command=self.pass_to_main)
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10), ipady=10, sticky="ewn")



Вы обращаетесь к test.title_info, но у вас test - это модуль, а не основное окно. У модуля test действительно нет атрибута title_info
У вас тут циклический импорт - файлы друг друга импортируют, так делать не нужно.
В идеале дочернее окно вообще не должно ничего знать про родительское (не должно пытаться писать в него какие-то значения), а должно просто возвращать результат. Примерный код как это можно реализовать:

import tkinter as tk


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        
        self.value = None  # По умолчанию результат None
        self.button_ok = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        self.button_ok.pack()
    
    def ok(self):
        # Записываем результат в атрибут объекта, потом закрываем окно
        self.value = self.entry.get()
        self.destroy()
    
    def wait_result(self):
        self.wait_window()  # Ждем закрытия окна
        return self.value  # Возвращаем результат


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Вызвать дочернее окно", command=self.show_child_window)
        self.button.pack()
        self.result_label = tk.Label(self, text="Тут будет результат")
        self.result_label.pack()
    
    def show_child_window(self):
        child = Child()
        
        # Ждем результат из дочернего окна, потом отображаем его в метке
        self.result_label.config(text=child.wait_result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()


Да я там намудрил с импортом но я ведь обращаюсь к атрибуту "title_info" класса Main а не к атрибуту самого модуля. И да, в одном файле у меня все работало но цель все же вынести TopLevel в отдельный файл - кода много. Спасибо!

"но я ведь обращаюсь к атрибуту "title_info" класса Main а не к атрибуту самого модуля" - нет вы именно импортируете модуль через import test, test - это именно модуль, и test.title_info - обращение к атрибуту модуля. Если бы вы делали импорт типа from test import main - это было бы импортирование объекта из модуля, но тут уже прилетит ошибка циклического импорта.

Вынести в отдельный модуль - без проблем, но выносимый класс либо вообще не должен знать о том, куда данные из него попадают, либо объект-получатель нужно передавать через параметр (как во втором ответе) - это будет что-то типа инъекции зависимости.

Да именно так я и сделал (как во втором ответе). Но большое спасибо за разъяснение про импорт про "инъекцию"!

Попробуйте так:
main.py:
import customtkinter

#import test2 as t2
# !!! +++
from q1580033_test2 import Top                                       # !!! +++


class Frame(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
# !!! +++        
        self.master = master                                         # !!! +++
        
        self.put_widget()

    def action_btn_signin(self):
# +++   vvvvvvvvvvv  <----------------------------------------------------
        self.master.title_info.configure(text="Open Toplevel")       # +++
#        t2.Top()
        Top(self.master)                                             # !!! +++

    def put_widget(self):
        self.btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, 
            text="open toplevel", command=self.action_btn_signin)
        self.btn.grid(row=1, column=0, 
            padx=20, pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")


class Main(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.put_widget()

    def put_widget(self):
        self.title_info = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Docs")
        self.title_info.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.info_frame = Frame(self)
        self.info_frame.configure(corner_radius=14)
        self.info_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(20, 5), pady=(20, 5))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()

q1580033_test2.py:
import customtkinter
#import test


class Top(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
# +++ -------------->  vvvvvv  <----------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, master):                                      # !!! +++
        super().__init__()
        self.master = master                                         # !!! +++
        
        self.put_widget()
        
        self.var = "main_window"

    def pass_to_main(self): 
        # Main.Main.title_info.configure(text=self.var)
# !!! +++
#        test.title_info.configure(text=self.var) 
# +++   vvvvvvvvvvv  <--------------------------------------------------------
        self.master.title_info.configure(text=self.var)              # !!! +++

        self.destroy() # +++ окно toplevel закрывается
        
    def put_widget(self):
        self.btn1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, 
            width=200, text="push", corner_radius=24, 
            font=("Arial", 18), command=self.pass_to_main)
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10), 
            ipady=10, sticky="ewn")




